# Merge [vba6] and [vba7] into [vba]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag has two version-specific cousins hanging around: [vba6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba6) and [vba7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba7). These two tags have a whopping 58 and 168 questions, respectively, compared to [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)'s ~200,000.

VBA 6, which came out right at the turn of the century, is almost certainly going to be the oldest version anyone asks a question about in Stack Overflow 22 years later. It certainly should be merged with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), since it is surely entirely synonymous (I can't find any tagged questions that mention using VBA version 5 on the site, at least).

VBA 7 is newer, sure, but the main difference is really just adding a LngPtr data type for 64-bit addresses... and that was still in 2010, shortly after the nascence of this very Q&A site. I'm sure there are some older questions (and maybe even a couple newer ones) that refer to Office 2007/2008 or older versions of applications that run VBA 6 at the latest, but most I'm sure are from app versions in the last 12 years. Worse, the only real feature of VBA 7 is referenced in [only 5 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+lngptr+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) ... and none of them have the [vba7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba7) tag (though a less strict search does show potentially [up to 100](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+long+pointer+is%3Aq&searchOn=3)). Most managed to get answers just fine despite lacking the version-specific tag, so it's clearly not that useful.

Granted, I don't think the differences here are substantive enough to necessitate an entirely separate tag. I mean the canonical ["what's the difference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072356/what-are-the-differences-between-vba-6-0-and-vba-7-0) question doesn't even use either of the version-specific tags (though it did briefly include [vba7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba7)...)

Unfortunately, because they are version tags, a moderator is required for synonymizing... hence this Meta request to alert them and get some community buy-in.

Comment: This seems completely reasonable; the question volume on the two version tags is very low, the tag excerpts are exact clones across all three tags... and half of all Q's tagged [[tag:vba6]] are _also_ tagged [[tag:vba7]], which heavily implies the version tags aren't really used as intended anyway a lot of the time. Merging them all will also help prevent [questions which only use the version tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28+%5Bvba6%5D+OR+%5Bvba7%5D+%29+-%5Bvba%5D) from falling through the cracks, too.

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes, thank you I completely forgot to mention the fact that the tag wikis are identical.

Comment: This is a colossally bad idea, as they differ too much. Q lazy Tag writer is no excuse to combine them

Comment: @nbk If you think there is too much if a difference, you should add an answer with data backing up the argument that shows, for example, some questions which would be harmed by a tag merge.

Comment: @nbk I'm not sure I can buy the argument they are so different that they need to exist as separate tags when VBA 7 just introduced 3 data types, its conflicts can be pretty much completely handled with some `Declare` statements, and when ~196,500 of the ~199,500 VBA questions on the site (that's 98.5% of all VBA questions!) have been asked (and mostly answered) just fine since the release of VBA 7 _without_ needing a VBA 7 tag...

Comment: How about making vba6 a synonym of vba, and making sure that all existing questions with the vba7 tag also have the generic tag? (I don't use VBA, so feel free to ignore me).

Comment: @PM2Ring That would be a good minimum step, for sure. Still would require a moderator, unfortunately :-(

Comment: @PM2Ring I would've thought what would make more sense is to make vba7 a synonym of VBA since when we talk about VBA it's almost always that version (it effectively is a synonym). VBA6 can then be kept to distinguish the older version.

Comment: +1 for using the word "nascence" in a sentence ;)

Answer (score 9):

I'd merge them all, with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) as the primary.

VBA questions that really are specifically about the very few VBA7-only things should be answerable by folks following the VBA tag, and nothing VBA is specific to VBA6 and/or inapplicable to VBA7; the version tags only serves to dilute things up and lose potential answerers that follow the VBA tag but not the less-used versioned ones. The vast majority of everything posted under VBA is also valid for both VBA6 and VBA7: DLL imports aren't all that common in VBA anyway, and when you see a `PtrSafe` modifier ([if ever](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bvba%5d%20%22PtrSafe%22)) you know you're looking at VBA7.

I think tagging with VBA+VBA6 or VBA+VBA7 is a waste of tag slots: what matters most importantly with VBA is what object model you're coding against / what your host application is, like Word, Access, or Excel; that leaves at most 3 slots for any other applicable tags (which is fine IMO), counting there's always a tag for the language, and another for the host application and/or relevant object model. Everything else is candy, including the actual specific version of VBA.

---

To me VBA6 and VBA7 don't bring much to the table as tags, especially more so now that the latest Office version to ship with VBA6 has been out of support for quite a long time: they're oxymorons of a tag that, if used alone (without a VBA tag), *could* risk keeping a good post under the radar... adding another tag for the host works well to get a question seen by the right specialists that know every intricacies of the object model you're working with.

If you're asking something specifically about VBA7 features, the post title, body, and code will make it pretty obvious. And if you asked about VBA6 *last decade* and tagged it VBA, it's very likely still valid and valuable content today for people working with VBA7.

Comment: Were you, somehow, using that abominable new editor to post this? Somehow, a bunch of Markdown in your post got escaped, resulting in the posting of raw Markdown instead of rendered text, and I just can't see how that would have been what you intended. (I've edited now, just pinging just in case I missed some reason for this.) Also, thanks for weighing in here; I love it when experts who actually use the tags to find questions take the time to post answers on these proposals!

Comment: I posted from mobile, ...thought something was weird. Thanks for the edits!

Comment: From my experience, the situations where VBA6/VBA7 are used correctly generally tend to be for host-agnostic questions diving deep where the host app really doesn't matter, so I don't but the argument about wasting the tag slot. [tag:python-3.x] has in big bold writing _USE ONLY IF YOUR QUESTION IS VERSION-SPECIFIC_. Given modern and 99% of VBA _is_ VBA7 (VBA7.1) I understand you may want to synonymise those. VBA6 is different and I think deserves its tag guidance to be modified, similar to python-3.x, with the additional stipulation that it must be used alongside [tag:vba] for discoverability

Comment: I would argue that the host application is equally irrelevant; if you're targeting objects from the host application, that comes under the heading "what object model you're coding against".

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, don't merge.

I/others have occasionally had to write code targeting VBA6 for backwards compatibility - e.g.

- [Is this pointer type watertight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827443/is-this-pointer-type-watertight)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252659/fast-native-memory-manipulation-in-vba (this post is on Code Review, where there are far fewer questions so version tags are less relevant. But this kind of content really shows the differences between the two versions of the language, in syntax and performance if you see the answers)

It is definitely not uncommon to write `#If VBA7 Then ...` conditional compilation for this reason. I think there is such a thing as being expert in these language versions, and it would be good if experts used these tags *more* as I'm sure there are many questions where it would actually be useful to have them and they are relevant. I believe VBA6 hung around on Mac Office for quite a while. I'd rather see the Tag wikis change.

Another point is that Google already sucks at searching for VBA6 vs VB6 vs countless other Visual Basic products (VB.Net) and I find for that reason the tags on SO are useful for discoverability. These questions I wrote would not make much sense with them synonymised:

- [What was the last common common ancestor of VBA6 and VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620823/what-was-the-last-common-common-ancestor-of-vba6-and-vb6)
- [VBA runtimes: msvbvm60.dll vs VBE7.DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011181/vba-runtimes-msvbvm60-dll-vs-vbe7-dll)

Comment: You can use the [tag:32-bit] tag instead to indicate you're dealing with VBA6; many VBA questions use bit-specific tags already. I don't think the questions you linked suffer much without the VBA6 tag considering they've gone this long without an answer in the first place... *while having* a [vba6] tag.

Comment: @TylerH Using the 32-bit tag would be misleading I feel as VBA7 code can be written and executed on 32 & 64 bit machines. `#If WIN64` is already used incorrectly because people conflate bitness with language version [and it is rarely needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56940710/6609896). Bitness is a difference but not the only one. Regarding the unanswered questions, I don't see how removing the tag would make them more likely to receive an answer, I can only hope it has meant more people have seen the questions so far but they are simply hard to answer. Could you expand?

Comment: Well you were talking about VBA6 questions, not VBA7 questions... so which one are you talking about? The 64-bit tag also exists and can be used for VBA7 questions. The point re: the unanswered questions is not that removing the tag would help, but that having the version-specific tag _did_ help (which is your argument). If you are going to argue that having the tag is useful, you need to show examples of questions where the tag helped get an answer. If you just show Qs w/ the tag that have no answer... that's not evidence of the tag providing a benefit, is it?

Comment: @TylerH What I mean to say is that [vba]+[64-bit] or [vba]+[32-bit] are not sufficient to replace [vba7] and [vba6] respectively: There is not a 1:1 correspondence (VBA7 questions may be about targeting 32-bit and vice-versa), and also the language change did more than just affect things to do with bitness (which is why `#If VBA7` and `#If WIN64` mean different things). Re unanswered questions; lack of answers doesn't mean the tags aren't attracting views and making answers more likely. Also, tags are not just about attracting answers, they also help people with the same question to filter Qus

Comment: 1) Your third link is arguably off-topic on StackOverflow, as it relates more to the history of VBA and VB6, rather than any specific concrete issue. 2) You yourself have written 171 posts with the [tag:vba] tag, but only two with either [tag:vb6] or [tag:vb7]. If someone is trying to find a question about a specific VBA6/7 compatibility issue, I think it better to rely on keyword search to find them, under the broarder [tag:vba] tag.

Comment: I don't use VBA, so I really don't have a horse in this race, but could we at minimum _clean up_ the [[tag:vba6]] tag to make it more useful? It's only got 58 questions (compared to [[tag:vba]]'s *200k*), has a duplicate tag excerpt to [vba], and literally exactly half of its questions [are also tagged with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba6+vba7) [[tag:vba7]], which implies to me that the tag, at the very least, isn't being used well in its current state.